# Add custom timestamp overlay on video with bash

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, overlay, vlc

Does anybody know a bash command for linux to write a custom timestamp ( DD:MM HH:MM:SS ) in a video file with ffmpeg, cvlc or any other program?

Comment: i talkin from unix timestamp. i know it is possible to make an overlay text with ffmpeg or vlc but i connot count it up

Comment: Uh didn't notice DD:MM. Then do you want a single timestamp throughout? I bet that would be simple. Otherwise (the exact timestamp at the exact frame) I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely.  I recently used this method to record quite a lot of video and timestamp it in realtime.

http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/

Comment: Answers should contain an actual answer instead of just being a link.

Comment: My appologies.  Try this:

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -s 640x480 -r 30 -vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='TYPESOMETHINGHERE': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k \
-preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4